# How do I change the background color of the body?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React.js and want to change the background color of the entire page. I can't figure out how to do this. Please help, thank you.

Edit (Sep 2 '18): I have a project on GitHub that I'm linking [here](https://github.com/osethan/TriangleSoloNoble). I don't have this project online right now, but in the `/client` folder is the client server. Check it out. This is how I answered the question.

Answer (score -10, accepted):

It's been a while since I asked this question. What I've started doing since then is using Facebook's `create-react-app` setup, and editing CSS files directly.

Comment: can you be more descriptive of what you did here

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question "How do I change the background color of the body?" You just said how you created the boilerplate and that you are "editing CSS files directly". 

That doesn't really explain what css you are using to do this (there is more than one way I believe), which files, how your getting a reference to the body, etc.

I hope I don't sound like a jerk, just didn't find the answer very descriptive. I got it to work using @Reni 's answer

Answer (score 57):

The simplest solution is a bit hacky, but you can use raw javascript to modify the body style:

```
document.body.style = 'background: red;';
// Or with CSS
document.body.classList.add('background-red');
```

A cleaner solution could be to use a head manager like [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) or [next.js `Head` component](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#populating-head).

```
import React from 'react';
import {Helmet} from 'react-helmet';

class Application extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
        <div className="application">
            <Helmet>
                <style>{'body { background-color: red; }'}</style>
            </Helmet>
            ...
        </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Some css-in-js also offers tools to manage global level styles; like [styled-components `injectGlobal`](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#injectglobal).

In the end, there's a lot of tools providing cleaner ways to handle this. But if you don't want to rely on third party, the raw JS option might be good enough if you don't make it too interactive.

Comment: Am I able to get document from within a reactjs component? I'm trying to do this now but not having any luck. `document` just comes back as undefined

Comment: @EthanDavis `document` is a global variable in the browser; you can access it from anywhere.

Comment: I'm rendering my reactjs from a nodejs server. `document` is undefined for me

Comment: @EthanDavis then the answer is going to be highly specific to how you architect your server side. But the same concept will stand true; you want to use raw JS to handle that as React doesn't render the `<body>` tag.

Comment: this is a clean solution ? to manipulate the dom directly from react, on componentwillmount ?

Comment: @rahulreddy no it is not super clean, I updated my answer with a few cleaner options that rely on 3rd party plugins.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias Yes i found React-helmet also as a very clean and good solution. And posted the answer since i didn't see that you had updated. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Can someone please explain why manipulating the document is not 'clean'?

Comment: @DaveHowson the reason is manipulating the document manually requires you to handle cleanup/updates manually. As such it's not ideal because it's more error prone and requires more manual work. That being said, it is a valid use-case and React doesn't make it hard to do. So I'd say it's okay to manipulate the document if you do not already use a framework/library that makes it easier.

Answer (score 29):

The simplest solution without doing anything fancy is to:

1) Open public/index.html

2) Add an inline style to your body like this: 
   `<body style="background-color: red">`

Comment: This is an extremely hard-coded solution very separate from other theming. Not good.

Comment: Ethan clearly didn't ask for a trivial solution like this.

Answer (score 27):

Try adding this to your code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"
}
```

Comment: Easiest solution of all !!!  :  useEffect(() => {  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red'  }, [])

Comment: Reactjs Component and Hooks can't in same file.

Comment: useLayoutEffect for maximum performance.

Answer (score 13):

**React Helmet** (https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet)

I really found this library  very helpfull. Really clean solution i would say.

Sample Usage:

```
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';

<Helmet bodyAttributes={{style: 'background-color : #fff'}}/>
```

Answer (score 13):

The above solutions tell about adding the external library to give the required functionality but instead what you can do is just go to your Index.css file and inside the already written 'body' tag put "background-color: 'color'" and its done

Answer (score 7):

If you want to change background color before the page loads you can do something like this.

```
import React, { useLayoutEffect } from 'react'
useLayoutEffect(() => {
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"
});
```

For further reference on useLayoutEffect check [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect)

Comment: What about if you want to set a gradient as bg color?

Comment: document.body.style.background = "linear-gradient(red, yellow)" it will work.

Answer (score 3):

After some time scouring the internet, I found this solution on a now deprecated github repo:

```js
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "INSERT_COLOR";
```

You can post it outside of your function (That's how I used it)

It worked for me in my project: https://github.com/antdke/styled-input-bar/blob/master/src/App.tsx

I needed it to color the background for the entire app.

Where I found the code snippet (At top of the README.md): https://github.com/happylinks/react-body-backgroundcolor

Hope it helps you all out like it helped me :)

Answer (score 3):

The basic idea is to use the browser API in raw JavaScript without installing any packages. I don't recommend to use `Helmet` because it is unsafe to the life cycle of a class component.

```js
// Update the document body background using the browser API
// in render() function for class component or directly in functional component
document.body.style.background = 'red';
```

---

**Other application:**

If you are constantly changing the body's background color, and you want to have the code to run on every render, following is an example. Be careful where you call the browser API.

For a **class component**, update it in `componentDidUpdate()`.

```js
import React from 'react';

class Example extends React.Component {
  // ...
  
  componentDidUpdate() {
    // change background color with a random color
    const color = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    document.body.style.background = color;
  }

  // ...
}
```

For a **functional component**, using Effect Hook `useEffect()`. You can look more into React Hook [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
  // ...

  // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate in class component:
  useEffect(() => {
    // change background color with a random color
    const color = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    document.body.style.background = color;
  }, []);

  // ...
}
```

Comment: both your react examples will cause the code to run on every render. You should update your example code or provide a note that lets readers know that the code block is executed after every render.

Comment: Thank you for catching it @SachinKumar! I have update my code and add a note to the readers.

Comment: If you want your react code to run only once, change the component's lifecycle for **componentDidMount** and add an empty array of dependencies for the **useEffect implementation**

Answer (score 2):

I just fiddled around with this for a bit. Simple solution for me, not entirely intuitive, all in `public/index.html`:

```
<html style="background-color: red">
```

that gets the *bottom* of the page, and a second entry:

```
<body style="background-color: red">
```

that gets you the *top* of the page ie. your react code.

Two entries for one problem but it's all in one file, needs no new libs and seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Please Don't need to install any packages is very easy and simple ! 
 add

```
 document.body.style = 'background: red;';
```

to your JS code or via CSS like below:

```js
const Changebackground = () => {
  const stylesObj = {
    background: "green"
  };

  return ( <
    div id = "hello-world"
    style = {
      stylesObj
    }
    className = "container" >
    <
    /div>
  )
}
export default Changebackground;
//ReactDOM.render( < Changebackground / > , document.getElementById('App'));
```

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -10;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

please check this one to see how its easy !
https://codepen.io/farbod-aprin/pen/dadJyb

Answer (score 2):

You should have a root component (e.g., a div) that is affected by the color you want as the background. That's the react-way to think about it.

```
  <div className ="bg-primary"> // this should cover everything in the background 
    <div className="container mx-auto bg-secondary"> // this could be a centered container that has a different color.
      <MyReactComponent />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The **style** property is not writable in Typescript but **setAttribute** works okay. Just pop it in your App component. It may not be a good idea to have a random bit of styling outside of React's many other styling mechanisms, it might make it hard to find, but if it's what you need it's what you need. It's what I needed today anyway!

```
    document.body.setAttribute('style', 'background: red;')
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue too and this is my solution.

```
body{
   margin:0;
   background-color:blue;
 }
```

Comment: This answer is unclear and could use some more description. What is that snippet and where does it go? How does it get included in the application?

Comment: @ptoinson The body css would be found in the index.css file.  The answer doesn't include this, because ReactJS developers are expected to know this as it is something from basic web development with HTML and CSS.

Comment: @ShamarYarde The OP appears to be a student of React, as are a lot of people who come and visit here. Answers are expected to be clear and descriptive. Posting a few lines of code is often not enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CSS module in React. Below is the Javascript code for a file named Home.js

```
import styles from './Home.module.css';

const Home = ()=>{
    return(

        <div className = {styles}>

        </div>
    );

}

export default Home;
```

And in a css module named Home.module.css (format is [name].module.css), put the following and your page will have a background colour of blue

```
body{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change that in the `App.css`, add `body{}` rule.

```css
body{
  background-color: red;
}

p{
  color: white;
}
```

```html
import './App.css';

function App() {
   return (
    <div>
      <p>Hello world!</p>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was simplest solution for me:

```
// in your css file

.background-white {
    background-color: white !important;
}


// in your react component

componentDidMount() {
    document.body.classList.add("background-white");
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    document.body.classList.remove("background-white");
}
```

Using componentWillMount did not work reliably. Using document.body.style did not work reliably either.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React with Bootstrap, just include a background-color Bootstrap class to the `<body>` tag, in the `index.html` file, like this:

```
<body class="bg-light">
```

You can choose other colors from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/colors/#background-color

Answer (score 0):

In your react src folder you should have a custom.css file.

Add 'body {background-color: ; }'  in that custom.css file.

Answer (score 0):

By default, assuming you've used *npx Create-React-app MyAppName* your React app will have an index.css.

This contains css which controls the default grey background. Just edit this to what you require.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #3f3f3f; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create index.css file like this

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}
```

Then import it in your index.ts file

```js
import "./index.css";
```

Also keep in mind the background color property might get overwritten if you import other css files below

So your index.ts file look like this

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "./index.css";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me as long as my body's data has content in it

`body { background-color : rgba(235,232,232,0.767); }`

Similarly, you can alter the root tag as well.

`#root{ background-color: rgba(235, 232, 232, 0.767); }`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use react-helmet-async rather than react-helmet
because it produces an error
`Using UNSAFE_componentWillMount in strict mode`

```
import { Helmet, HelmetProvider } from 'react-helmet-async';
class Application extends React.Component {
 render () {
  return (
    <HelmetProvider>
      <div>
        <Helmet>
            <style>{'body { background-color: red; }'}</style>
        </Helmet>
        ...
      </div>
   </HelmetProvider>
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make a wrapper componenet with an id like "wrapper" and then create a style with the color state:

```javascript
getInitialState: function () {
  return { color: "white" }; // Set your color for initial state.
},

changeColor: function () {
  this.setState({ color: "black" }); // Set your changed color.
},

render: function () {
  var style = { backgroundColor: this.state.color };
  // The wrapper (root) component
  return (
    <div id="fullscreen" style={style}>
       <a onClick={this.changeColor}>change</a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The result should be something like:

```html
<body>
    <div id="fullscreen" style="background-color: YOUR CUSTOM COLOR">
        <a onclick="THE REACT FUNCTION"></a>
    </div>
</body>
```